# linux file -i command outputs octet/stream for every media file

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, files, mime

On Linux / Unix Command file:

" -i   Causes the file command to output mime type strings rather than the more traditional human readable ones "

Why does it always output "application/octet-stream" for images and videos?
How can I obtain the specific mime type of an image or a video with this command or with any other command?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output without -i ?

Comment: Without -i the output gives details about the format, for example, "Macromedia Flash Video"

Comment: This may be a better candidate for http://superuser.com, BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell us what the output is with out the -i switch?

Also, what is the output of the `file --version`, maybe you are missing magic files?

```
file --version
file-4.26
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/file/magic
```

You might just need to update your magic package (I love how these sentances sound :-) ).  Do so on debian / ubuntu :

```
apt-get install libmagic1
```

Comment: file someflv.flv: /tmp/phpGo4d1V: Macromedia Flash Video ||| file -i someflev.flv: /tmp/phpGo4d1V: application/octet-stream ||| file --version file-4.17 magic file from /usr/share/file/magic –

Comment: Output of `grep flv /usr/share/file/magic` ?

Comment: Or maybe you need: /usr/share/file/magic.mime ?

Comment: The output is empty then I guess "update" is the correct answer. I will tell my sysadmin about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar under Ubuntu 9.10 while it was working in Ubuntu 9.04.

Had `libmagic1` and `libmagic-dev` installed with the following:

```
$ file --version
file-5.03
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

`/etc/magic` has only a couple comments (in 9.10 and 9.04)
`/usr/share/misc/magic` is a symlink to `../file/magic`

I managed to solve the problem by downgrading file and libmagic. I installed these versions from Jaunty:

- libmagic1_4.26-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
- file_4.26-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb

Things *seem* to be working now, but I don't know if it'll cause other issues.